# Detectar registros ya existentes - Laravel / REST-API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Verán ando creando en mi proyecto una sección para registrar los departamentos de un país, el problema es que deseo qué los departamentos existentes no me los cree de nuevo.

```
$isset_departamento = Departamento::where('nombre', '=', $departamento)->get()->count();

if($isset_departamento == 0) {
  $departamento->save();

  $data = array(
    'status' => 'success',
    'code' => '200',
    'message' => 'Departamento registrado correctamente.'
 );
} else {
  $data = array(
    'status' => 'error',
    'code' => '400',
    'message' => 'Ya existe un departamento registrado con este nombre.'
);
}
```

Comment: El problema es qué creo un apartamento con el mismo nombre  y me lo acepta, es decir, no detecta qué el departamento ya existe y lo crea de nuevo, no pasa por el else.

Comment: Prueba utilizando `first()` en lugar de `get()->count()`, en tu if solo escribe `$isset_departamento == null` y debería funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes ahí, es que en `$departamento` hay un objeto en vez del `string` con el nombre. Y digo esto porque dices que se cumple condición del `if($isset_departamento == 0)` y te inserta el registro con `$departamento->save();`.

Para seguir en la misma línea en la que lo vienes trabajando, tu consulta debería ser así:

```
$isset_departamento = Departamento::where('nombre', $departamento->nombre)->count();
```

Donde comparas el valor de la columna `nombre` con la propiedad `nombre` del objeto y cuentas los registros que cumplen la condición.

---

Si el valor viene de una solicitud entrante, te evitarías todo ese rollo haciendo la correspondiente validación:

```
$request->validate([
    'nombre' => 'unique:App\Models\Departamento,nombre',
]);
```

---

Y otra buena práctica sería a nivel base de datos, indexando esa columna como `unique`

```
Schema::table('departamentos', function ($table) {
    $table->string('nombre')->unique();
});
```

Y puedes hacer un catch de la consulta:

```
try {
    $departamento->save();

    $data = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'code' => '200',
        'message' => 'Departamento registrado correctamente.'
    );
} catch (Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e){
    $errorCode = $e->errorInfo[1];
    if($errorCode == 1062) {
        $data = array(
            'status' => 'error',
            'code' => '400',
            'message' => 'Ya existe un departamento registrado con este nombre.'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: vi tú comentario dónde se explica de forma detallada como es el funcionamiento de la página, muchísimas gracias, lo tendré en cuenta para próximas ocasiones